# LAN & multiplayer game for Ubucon

Tags: games

In the next Ubucon Europe we would like to do a party with a game.

The game has these needs:

- Multiplayer.
- LAN party.
- Server setup controlling the game.

I know is very easy to config a few of them (teeworlds for example). Could you tell us games (better free license)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OpenArena, Xonotic, maybe also SuperTuxKart if they finally implemented it (I haven't checked in a while).

Comment: OAD! Westnoth! Minetest?